# Initialize a slick slider in a Foundation 6 responsive accordion tabs container

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to initialize several slick sliders in a Foundation 6 responsive accordion/tabs container. I can get the tabs working fine, but not in the accordion.... here is the container for the tab/accordioni nav:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-responsive-accordion-tabs="tabs small-accordion medium-tabs" id="homeContentTabs">
    <li class="tabs-title is-active slickTrigger" data-tab-target="slickFeatured"><a href="#featured" aria-selected="true">Featured Events</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title slickTrigger" data-tab-target="slickLatest"><a href="#latest">Latest Videos</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title slickTrigger" data-tab-target="slickViewed"><a href="#viewed">Most Viewed</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title yourContent slickTrigger" data-tab-target="slickSaved"><a  href="#saved">Your Content</a></li>
</ul>
```

and some javascript:

```
$('[data-responsive-accordion-tabs]').on('change.zf.tabs up.zf.accordion down.zf.accordion', function(event, tab) {
    var target = '.'+$(tab).attr('data-tab-target');
    $(target).slick({--slick options-- });
});
```

so what seems to happen is that when someone clicks on a list element the foundation plugin is using the li element as the `currentTarget`,  on an up or down accordion event, it seems to be trying to use the `a` element? 
Anyone know how to get the value for data-tab-target from the li element in either case?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

I solved the problem like this:

```
// find and initialize any ~visible~ slick elements
$('.slick-carousel').each(function(){
    var slickHidden =$(this).parent().attr('aria-hidden');
    var target = $(this).attr('id');
    var view = $(this).attr('data-view');
    if(!slickHidden){
        slickInit(target,view);
    }
})


// init slick on tab/accordion click
$('[data-responsive-accordion-tabs]').on('change.zf.tabs down.zf.accordion', function(event, obj) {
    // target can be either a tab or link in accordion title
    var target = $(obj).attr('data-tab-target');
    if(!target){
        var target = $(obj).parent().attr('data-tab-target');
    }
    // test if target is already init, if no ~ init! 
    if(!$('#'+target).hasClass('slick-initialized')){
        slickInit(target);
    }

});


// initialize slick target
function slickInit(target,view){
    // initialize slick
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, foundation accordion with it having a display: none slick cannot find the height and breaks.

Below worked for me, you need to initialise slick when the accordion is open, foundation has built in events that you can use.

```
$('.faq').on('down.zf.accordion', function () {
    $('.faq_slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        arrows: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: problem is that for the tabs/accordion behavior the elements are removed and replaced ...  so you can't init them normally...   I did find a solution & updated my question.

Comment: @SeanKimball please post your solution as an answer